# Как найти проиндексированные страницы и сделать переадресацию на новый сайт?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, индексация

Как найти проиндексированные страницы 
и есть ли инструмент, позволяющий определить проиндексированные страницы?
сайт на вордпресс

**P.S.**
site:www.site.com

я так понял как-то так.
А подскажите, если нужно со старого сайта сделать переадресацию на новый сайт всех проиндексированных страниц старого сайта, это нужно в файле htaccess добавить все ссылки, которые выдал данный запрос? `site:www.site.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Можно выгрузить sitemap.xml текущего сайта и сделать правила на
  301-редиректах. То есть плясать не от индексации, а от текущей
  структуры URL.
- Если нужны только страницы из индекса, подключите    Google Search
  Console и возьмите адреса оттуда    https://www.google.ru/webmasters/

Как я понимаю, у вас новый домен?